# Is there any easy way to undo put if I selected the wrong register?

Tags: register

Sometimes I accidently put from the wrong register and end up hitting u to undo, but then I have to reselect the text that I was trying to replace. Is there an easy way to either reapply the put from the correct register or undo and restore the text that was previously selected?

Comment: `gv` will reselect your last selection.

Comment: @paradroid That looks like an answer to me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you `put` the normal register are not modified apart from the `"` (and `*` if you are using `clipboard unnamed` setting) register that are replaced by the content that you override.

To avoid that behavior some use the mapping:

```
xnoremap p pgvy
```

It restores the content of the `"` to the value that has just been pasted.

A more advance version of this mapping does it only if you have used the `"` register to paste:

```
xnoremap <expr> p v:register=='"'?'pgvy':'p'
```

Comment: `:help v_P` in recent Vim

Comment: Oh nice. This should be a default mapping.

Comment: O that is an interesting approach to it! Thanks for the tip.

Comment: You are welcome :-) If it solve your problem don't forget to accept the solution.